# Nav menu is showing up pressed together in only Safari. Thoughts?

Tags: html, css, browser, safari, zurb-foundation

I made this [website](http://simplewebcomics.com) using Zurb foundation framework, and to get a handrawn design for the nav menu I had to do it in a somewhat roundabout way. Here is the way I implemented it:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 columns">
      <h1><a href="index.html"><img width="100px" height="100px" src="img/logo.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/logo_bold.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='img/logo.png'"></a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="large-9 columns">
      <ul class="right button-group">

      <li><a href="features.html"><img class="nav_img" src="img/features.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/features_bold.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='img/features.png'"></a></li>
      <li><a href="download.html"><img class="nav_img" src="img/download.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/download_bold.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='img/download.png'"></a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php"><img class="nav_img" src="img/contact.png"onmouseover="this.src='img/contact_bold.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='img/contact.png'"></a></li>

      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now whenever it is opened in safari 6.0.5 the nav gets squished together like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7SFI.png). Any thoughts on a workaround for safari?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue in Safari Mac 5.1.10 (6534.59.10). What version are you using?

Comment: Looks ok on my phone's Safari.  Although resolutions are different, I dont get the squished look. Sounds weird that it would work on Chrome and not on Safari.

Comment: I am using Safari 6.0.5

Answer (score 0):

**It's the "Touch Events" in `custom.modernizr.js`. Remove that and you're good to go.**

Here's a link to the same build but minus Touch Events:
http://modernizr.com/download/#-inlinesvg-svg-svgclippaths-shiv-mq-cssclasses-teststyles-prefixes-ie8compat-load

If you want to optimize for mobile/touch devices, one big improvement would be CSS sprites instead of js rollovers. Here's a dated but great [CSS tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) on the subject.